# Invalid hook call error message, but everything on my terminal seems good

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
   [![img1][1]][1]        
   [img2][2]
   [![img3][3]][3]
   [![img4][4]][4]
   [![img5][5]][5]

   import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
   import Navbar from "../../Component/Navbar";
   import "./counter.scss";
    
        const Counter = () => {
        const [timerDays, setTimerDays] = useState("00");
        const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState("00");
        const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState("00");
        const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState("00");
    
        let interval = useRef();
    
        const startTimer = () => {
            const countdownDate = new Date("May 18, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                const now = new Date().getTime();
                const distance = countdownDate - now;
    
                const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60)));
                const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
                if(distance > 0) {
                    // STOPPING THE TIMER
                    clearInterval(interval.current);
                } else {
                    // UPDATING THE TIMER
                    setTimerDays(days);
                    setTimerHours(hours);
                    setTimerMinutes(minutes);
                    setTimerSeconds(seconds);
                }
    
            }, 1000);
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            startTimer();
            return () => {
                clearInterval(interval);  
            }
        })
    
        return (
            <section className="countdown__container">   
                <Navbar />
                <div className="countdown__timer">
                    <div className="countdown__border">
                        <div>
                            <p><small>Days</small></p>
                            <p>{timerDays}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>:</span>
                    <div className="countdown__border">
                        <div>
                            <p><small>Hours</small></p>
                            <p>{timerHours}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>:</span>
                    <div className="countdown__border">
                        <div>
                            <p><small>Minutes</small></p>
                            <p>{timerMinutes}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>:</span>
                    <div className="countdown__border">
                        <div>
                            <p><small>Seconds</small></p>
                            <p>{timerSeconds}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    
                </div>
            </section>
        )
        }
    
        export default Counter;
    
    {Navbar component}
    import React from 'react';
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import SwirgeFinanceLogo from "../../assets/images/finance_logo.svg";
    import "./index.scss";
    
    const Navbar = () => {
    
        const [ isMobile, setIsMobile ] = React.useState(false)
    
        return (
                <nav className="navbar">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar__logo">
                        <img src={SwirgeFinanceLogo} alt="home__logo" />
                    </Link>
                    <ul 
                        className={ isMobile ? "nav__link__mobile" : "nav__link"}
                        onClick={() => setIsMobile(false)}
                    >
                        <Link to="/" className="home">
                            <li>Home</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="features">
                            <li>Features</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="about">
                            <li>About Us</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="faq">
                            <li>FAQ</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="team">
                            <li>Team</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="github">
                            <li>Github</li>
                        </Link>
                        <Link to="/" className="contact">
                            <li>Contact</li>
                        </Link>
                        <button 
                            className="mobile__menu__icon"
                            onClick={() => setIsMobile(!isMobile)}
                        >
                            {isMobile ? (
                                <i className="fas fa-times"></i>
                            ) : (
                                <i className="fas fa-bars"></i>
                            )}
                        </button>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        )
    }
    
    export default Navbar
```

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
   and fix this problem.

Please I've tried all solutions, I can find but it still has this logical
error message

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKT0E.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cueqn.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yve1m.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmrYT.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4u1Z.png
```

Comment: share your navbar compoment also.

Comment: You code for this component is fine. There are no issues. When you received an error, there should be some line number and file name as well. Post the code that file.

Comment: Since interval is a useRef is it valid to use "interval = setInterval(() => {" or do you have to assign the response to interval.current?

Comment: @NisanthReddy I tried

Comment: @FerinPatel I've shared it

Comment: @Atmas how do you mean?

Comment: Nowhere in your code is there anything close to `https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKT0E.png`.  Is there further portions of this code you did not post?  If not, post full please.

Comment: Meaning do you instead have to write the line as "interval.current = setInterval(() => {".. because interval is one of your hooks. Perhaps directly setting it like you have is corrupting it. Refs trip me up so I may be wrong but it's easy enough to try it on your side.

Comment: Also your effect calls clear interval on the ref in one part of the code but uses interval.current to do the same in another. I think using .current is actually correct when you're dealing with refs so maybe change the 2nd clearInterval too.